# How do I work with many-to-many relations in Yii2

Tags: php, many-to-many, yii2

For example in one-to-many due to documentation (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data) you can link two models in this way `(one-many = company-zone)`:

```
$defaultZone = new Zone;
$defaultZone->name = Zone::DEFAULT_ZONE;
$company->link('zones', $defaultZone);
```

But how it works for many-to-many relations when you have transit table like `tbl_user_market(user_id, market_id)`?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

When using a junction table for many-to-many relations, you have to

1. Define the relations
2. Link the two models together

In the User model define the following relation function:

```
public function getMarkets() {
    return $this->hasMany(Market::className(), ['id' => 'market_id'])
      ->viaTable('tbl_user_market', ['user_id' => 'id']);
}
```

In the Market model define the following relation function:

```
public function getUsers() {
    return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ['id' => 'user_id'])
      ->viaTable('tbl_user_market', ['market_id' => 'id']);
}
```

And finally, after saving both models, link them together:

```
$user = new User;
$user->name = 'Foo';
$user->save();

$market = new Market;
$market->name = 'Bar';
$market->save();

$user->link('markets', $market);
```

The call to `link()` will populate the junction table.

Reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#link()-detail

Comment: @onegun: When you call save() on a model, Yii determines whether to perform an update or insert query. That's the beauty of such a framework, you don't have to worry about things like that anymore.

Comment: I created a behavior to help saving multiple links - http://github.com/cornernote/yii2-linkall `User::findOne(1)->linkAll('markets', [Market::findOne(2), Market::findOne(3)], true);`, it looks after removing old links and adding the new ones.

Comment: You can also use ManyToMany Behavior. See: https://github.com/voskobovich/ManyToManyBehavior

Comment: @vim, Could you please add to your answer how to load the Market entity with pre-populated 'users' attribute?