# Yii2 activeDropDownList fundamentals

Tags: yii2

I'm new to Yii2 but not to MVC (trying to move my focus from MS to Yii2). I've scaffolded up an app from my DB using gii.  I have a table called track I have a table called music_category.  There's a n:n relationship via a link table called track_has_music_category.      My track model (as scaffolded by gii) has a function

```
 public function getMusicCategories()
{
    return $this->hasMany(MusicCategory::className(), ['id' => 'music_category_id'])->viaTable('track_has_music_category', ['track_id' => 'id']);
}
```

But that is for retrieving the categories that have been 'link'ed to this track.  So I guess I need something like

```
<?= Html::activeDropDownList(theCategoryModel (syntax here??), 'id', ArrayHelper::map(theCategoryModel->findAll(),'id', ''description)) ?>
```

Well, something like that.  I feel as though the online reference could do with  a few worked examples.

Any help much appreciated.

Cheers
Mark

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we want to attach some categories to a track model ($model):

```
echo Html::activeCheckboxList($model, 'musicCategories', ArrayHelper::map(MusicCategory::findAll(),'id', ''description))
```

We use `activeCheckboxList` here since it's a multiple relation.
Although you will need to add extra $model logic to save these relations. 
Have a look at this [How do I work with many-to-many relations in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763298/how-do-i-work-with-many-to-many-relations-in-yii2)

Comment: Yes that might be better than the drop-down for n:n.  I got a drop-down loading last night around midnight ... thinking I'll cross the many to many bridge when I get there but that's given me a good look ahead.  Thanks.