# YII2 how do i handle many to many relationships?

Tags: php, sql, yii2, many-to-many

I am new to YII2 and I have a problem with my relationships:

I have Users and Category. They have a m-m relationship. Now i would like to see the Categories a user has. For that I made a table named "user_category" which looks as follows:
[image]

In my models i have the following code as suggested in 
[How do I work with many-to-many relations in Yii2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26763298/how-do-i-work-with-many-to-many-relations-in-yii2) :

```
public function getUsers(){
    return $this->hasMany(TabUser::className(), ['intUserID' => 'intUserID'])
        ->viaTable('user_category', ['intCategoryID' => 'intCategoryID']);
}
public function getCategories(){
    return $this->hasMany(TabCategory::className(), ['intCategoryID' => 'intCategoryID'])
        ->viaTable('user_category', ['intUserID' => 'intUserID']);
}
```

Then i linked them together:

```
if($user->validate()) {
        $user->link('categories', $category);
    }

    var_dump($user->getCategories());
```

But this does not return my categories it returns the following: 
[image]

Does anybody know what I do wrong?

Thanks for your time and help!!

Comment: Maybe this can help you [https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/780/drills-search-by-a-hasmany-relation-in-yii-2-0](https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/780/drills-search-by-a-hasmany-relation-in-yii-2-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method getCategories() returns ActiveQuery object instead of models. If you need to get an array of category models you must use magical property `categories`. For example:

```
var_dump($user->categories);
```

Comment: Thanks this has been helpful. I know it is not part of the question but you seem to have a clue. Do you know how to create a user with checkboxes for the categories?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/voskobovich/yii2-many-to-many-behavior to saving a category list

Answer (score 1):

Try to divide your expression like this, should work:

```
$categories = $user->categories;
var_dump($categories);
```